# Datasource Location not working as expected

Tags: experience-editor, jss, datasource

I created a rendering for my form and linked the datasource location to sitecore/forms (which should be correct).

The mysterious thing about this is that when I select my rendering in the experience editor, the only option i get to select is the page components which shouldn't be showing up at all since the datasource location is set to sitecore/forms.

I tried to reset both server and browser, cleared cachefiles and so on, still not working.

Following is what I insert in Datasource Location,

[image]

And this is what I see when I select the rendering in the experience editor.

[image]

Anyone got a clue about what might be wrong here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98494/discussion-on-question-by-robin-lundgren-datasource-location-not-working-as-expe).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I solved it by writing `query:` in front of `/sitecore/Forms` in the Datasource Location, so that the datasource location says `query:/sitecore/Forms`

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, i solved it with the following powershell script.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -path "master:/sitecore/layout/Renderings" -recurse
foreach($item in $items) {
    if($item.TemplateName -eq "Controller rendering" -Or $item.TemplateName -eq "View rendering") {
        $location = $item.Fields["Datasource Location"].Value
        if(!$location.StartsWith("query:") -And $location -ne "") {
            $newLocation = "query:"+$location
            $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
            $item.Fields["Datasource Location"].Value = $newLocation
            $item.Editing.EndEdit()
            Write-Host $item.Name": "$item.Fields["Datasource Location"]
        }
        if($location -eq "") {
            $baseLocation = "query:/sitecore/content/DELA/Home/Global/Datasources"
            $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
            $item.Fields["Datasource Location"].Value = $baseLocation
            $item.Editing.EndEdit()
            Write-Host $item.Name": "$item.Fields["Datasource Location"]
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your situation you can change this script.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me.  Until I get the hotfix, this was a perfect solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hotfix from support by giving them the reference number 413366. It's not exaclty the problem, but we got for the reference number a hotfix, which is for more than one bug.

Comment: While answers like this are not ideal, sometimes that's all the answer you can really give. "It's a bug, you can request a hotfix, here is the reference number".

Comment: Damn right, thanks Mark! I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though i couldn't find an answer why datasource location didnt work in the content editor, i found a way to set datasource location in the experience editor.

In order to make this work I had to leave the datasource location input field in the content editor empty.

Then select my rendering in the experience editor with the checkbox "Open the Properties dialog box immediately" checked.

This allowed me to set the datasource location along with some other things in a window called "Experience Editor Options" and the form now worked as intended.

[image]

Even though I managed to fix this issue of mine. I still considering reinstalling Sitecore in the hopes of making it able to set the datasource location via det content editor since thats how it's suppose to work.

Comment: Did reinstalling Sitecore fix the issue?