# Not able to point to correct datasource location after upgrading Sitecore 9.0.1 to 9.2

Tags: experience-editor, datasource

We recently migrated our site from 9.0.1 instance to 9.2. Everything works fine except that when I select a rendering in experience editor and try to locate the Datasource location for creating/ selecting a datasource it points to an abrupt parent and not the path that i had set in my datasouce location field in the rendering.

This was working fine on 9.0.1 but giving an issue on 9.2.
I know the fix to it is mentioned in [Datasource Location not working as expected](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20951/datasource-location-not-working-as-expected) , but i will have to attach the "query:/" string before every datasouce location in every rendering and we have a lot of renderings.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take this to Sitecore Support. They have a hotfix for that. Be sure to detail the information you get back in an answer below.

Comment: Thanks @MarkCassidy. I have raised a ticket with Sitecore support. Will put in the details when available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore support came to help at last! So yes, this is a known bug and Sitecore provides a hotfix package for the same. So in case you have the same issue you can approach Sitecore to get the hotfix package. Be sure to read the readme files so that you are aware about which dll's are impacted by this package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take help of Powershell extension for -

> i will have to attach the "query:/" string before every datasouce location in every rendering and we have a lot of renderings.

You can probably make use of method described at -

> https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/presentation/set-rendering

Comment: Thanks for the response Ghanendra but running power shell scripts is not my first preference since datasource location pointing is the default Sitecore functionality and it should have worked OOTB. So i am seeking for a more concrete solution.